# EWS Managed API TimeZoneDefinition header not sent when forwarding

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We recently upgraded to Exchange 2013 and discovered that the EWS Managed API does not actually send the TimeZoneDefinition header when sending a Forward in this version (in fact it seems to only do so for 2007_SP1 which we were using).  So I googled a bit and found an event I could wire that would supposedly write this header to the request on serialization.  Unfortunately this doesn't work.  The code executes but when the end-user receives the forwarded email the original send date is still in UTC instead of their time zone (with which I initialize the service client).  Can anyone see why this is not working?  Here's the setup and send:

```
var emailForward = originalEmail.CreateForward();
emailForward.ToRecipients.Add(recipient);
emailForward.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Drafts);

_service.OnSerializeCustomSoapHeaders += ServiceOnSerializeAddTimeZoneDefinitionSoapHeader;

emailForward.Send();

_service.OnSerializeCustomSoapHeaders -= ServiceOnSerializeAddTimeZoneDefinitionSoapHeader;
```

Here's the event handler:

```
private void ServiceOnSerializeAddTimeZoneDefinitionSoapHeader(XmlWriter writer)
{
   writer.WriteRaw(Environment.NewLine + "    <t:TimeZoneContext><t:TimeZoneDefinition Id=\"" + _service.TimeZone.StandardName + "\"/></t:TimeZoneContext>" + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using new features, you can continue to use the Exchange2007_SP1 version when initializing your ExchangeService object.

If you are using new features, then I would first verify that the element you're adding actually goes on the wire. [Enable tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn495632(v=exchg.150).aspx) and see if it is included.

Another option would be to fix the Managed API to emit the header automatically. The API is open-sourced now, so you could modify it: https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/. As a test, I modified `EmitTimeZoneHeader` in [CreateItemRequestBase.cs](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/blob/master/Core/Requests/CreateItemRequestBase.cs) as follows:

```
internal override bool EmitTimeZoneHeader
{
    get
    {
        foreach (TServiceObject serviceObject in this.Items)
        {
            // BEGIN MODIFICATION
            // Handle reply/forward case specially
            if (serviceObject is ResponseMessage)
            {
                return true;
            }
            // END MODIFICATION

            if (serviceObject.GetIsTimeZoneHeaderRequired(false /* isUpdateOperation */))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

That worked for me.

Comment: Brilliant!  I keep being taken by surprise when learning about something Microsoft has open-sourced.  This worked like a charm.  Thanks man.  Note to anyone else going this route - the Master Git branch of this project does not contain the required .resx for the resulting DLL to function.  Make sure to get the adding-resx branch: https://github.com/LukeMarlin/ews-managed-api/tree/adding-resx